# How to save dynamic fields data into database using react.js and node.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post

I have a form in react.js in which there are some fields that ultimately save into the database on submit. But I want to add dynamic input fields that ultimately save into the database as an array. The code of the frontend is given below and it is working but the data I am writing in these fields are not saving into the database.

```
   const linksTemplate={linkName:"",link:""}
    const [downloadLinks,setDownloadLinks] =useState([linksTemplate])

  const addLink=()=>{
      setDownloadLinks([...downloadLinks,linksTemplate])
  }
  const changeHandler=(e,index)=>{
      const updatedLink=downloadLinks.map((newLink,i)=>index===i ? Object.assign(newLink,{[e.target.name]:e.target.value}):newLink)
  setDownloadLinks(updatedLink);
  console.log(updatedLink)
  }

  const removeLink=(i)=>{
      const filteredLinks=[...downloadLinks]
      filteredLinks.splice(i,1);
      setDownloadLinks(filteredLinks)

  }
    const publish = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        createMaterial(formData, token).then(data => {
            if (data.error) {
                setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
            } else {
               
                setDownloadLinks([...downloadLinks,[{linkName:"",link:""}]])
            }
        });
    };

return(
<form  onSubmit={publish}>
{downloadLinks.map((exactLink,index)=>(

    <div className="p-1 my-1" key={index} style={{border:'1px solid #00c1b2',borderRadius:'0.6rem'}}>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder='Title of Link' name="linkName" value={exactLink.linkName} onChange={e=>changeHandler(e,index)} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder='Link' value={exactLink.link} name="link" onChange={e=>changeHandler(e,index)} />
            </div>
            <button className="btn nbtn btn-primary m-1" onClick={addLink}>Add</button>
            <button className="btn nbtn btn-danger" onClick={removeLink}>Delete</button>

            </div>

))}

</form>
```

My guess is the problem is the naming of the fields. Please help if you found something wrong with the code.

The backend code is:

```
exports.create = async (req, res) => {
    try {
         let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
     form.keepExtensions = true;
     form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
         if (err) {
             return res.status(400).json({
                 error: 'Image could not upload'
             });
         }
 
 const 
{title,forSlug,subtitle,language,desc,materialCategories,mainCat,subCat,standard,materialType,linkName,link, body } = fields;
 
  
 
 
         let material = new Material();
         material.materialType =materialType;
         material.downloadLink.linkName =linkName;
         material.downloadLink.link =link;



 
         material.save((err, result) => {
             if (err) {
                 console.log(err)
                 return res.status(400).json({
                     error: errorHandler(err)
                 });
             }
 
    } catch (err) {
         console.error(err.message);
          res.status(500).send('Server error');
    }
 };
```

Comment: A minimal replication with codesandbox at least for UI will be helpful

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-taussig-573fo?file=/src/App.js .The is what I want at the frontend but I am unable to save the data written in these fields at the backend Can you tell me the proper naming of these fields at the backend. These fields are basiclly the part of the blogSchema.Hence insde blogSchema it looks like        downloadLink:[{
          linkName:{
              type:String,

          },
          link:{
              type:String
          }
        
        }],